# LG G2 getting sluggier by the day

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, performance, lg-g2

I'm not sure if this is specific to this model or not, but I am having troubles understanding how four cores of over 2GHz can perform so miserably slow.

During the last few days, it's gotten to the point where if I am typing, I have to pause between words, or the new word will replace the old one in the text.

I am running CPU-Z right now, and doing nothing else. It shows my CPU load to oscillate wildly between 17% and 62%, fwiw.

Where do I begin to look for bottlenecks?

List of installed apps (a hefty lot):

```
#sworcery
    com.capybaragames.sworcery.humble
AirStream
    com.nityaalabs.airstream
AirVid
    com.sb.airvid
Aktivitetsh.
    com.lge.lmk
Anodyne
    air.Anodyne.humble
Another World
    com.dotemu.anotherworld.humble
Aquaria
    com.bit_blot.aquaria_humble
Arla Kökets kokbok
    arla.activities
ATG WebApp
    se.sapio.webAppBrowser.prod
Audio Book Player (Ad)
    com.frma.audioBookPlayer2
BaconReader
    com.onelouder.baconreader
BankID
    com.bankid.bus
Barcode Scanner
    com.google.zxing.client.android
Bard's Tale
    com.inxile.BardTale
Beat Hazard
    com.coldbeamgames.beathazardultrahumblefull
Betapet FREE
    com.betapet.mobile.se.free
BIT.TRIP BEAT
    com.gaijingames.bittripbeat.humble
Bladeslinger
    com.kerosenegames.bsep1hib
Blockdroid
    org.blockdroid
Bloons TD 5
    com.ninjakiwi.bloonstd5.humble
Bredbandskollen
    se.iis.bbk
Broken Sword
    uk.co.revolution.bs1dc.humblebundle
Canabalt HD
    fishnoodle.canabalt_humble
Canon EPP
    jp.co.canon.bsd.android.aepp.activity
Carmageddon
    com.stainlessgames.carmageddonhumble
Catan
    com.exozet.android.catan
ChatON
    com.sec.chaton
Chromecast
    com.google.android.apps.chromecast.app
Cogs
    com.lazy8studios.cogs.humble
Contre Jour
    com.chillingo.contrejour.android.humblebundle
CPU Spy Plus - Free
    com.bvalosek.cpuspy.realgpp
CPU-Z
    com.cpuid.cpu_z
Crayon Physics DLX
    com.kloonigames.crayon.humble
CupOnline
    se.cuponline.mobile
Den Lilla Prinsen
    com.lge.livewallpaper.prince
Desert Bus
    com.amateurpixels.DesertBus.humble
DioDict3 ENG-ESP
    com.diotek.diodict3.lgedict.adddict.engesp
Dungeon Defenders: Second Wave
    com.trendy.ddapp
Dynamite Jack
    com.galcon.dynamitejack.humble
EDGE
    net.mobigame.edge.humble
EDGE EX
    net.mobigame.edge.extended.humble
Elemental Kingdoms
    air.com.perfectworld.ek
Eniro
    com.eniro
EPOCH
    com.uppercut_games.epochhumble
Facebook
    com.facebook.katana
Family Protection
    com.mcafee.android.familyprotection
Fieldrunners
    com.subatomicstudios.humble
Find More Like This
    com.bjbinc.searchbyimage
Fjäder
    com.lge.livewallpaper.feather
Flappy Bird
    com.dotgears.flappybird
Fractal
    com.cipherprime.fractal.humble
GetAway
    com.MiLuGames.GetAway
GladaLunchen
    com.LunchApp.Menu
God of Blades
    com.whitewhalegames.godofblades.humble
Greed Corp
    com.invictus.greedcorp.humble
HBO Nordic
    com.hbo.android.app
Hemköp
    se.axfood.hemkop
Hitta.se
    se.hitta.android.app
Home Theme - MarshMallow
    com.lge.launcher2.theme.marshmallow
Humble Bundle (beta)
    com.humblebundle.library
Hundreds
    com.semisecretsoftware.Hundreds.humble
IAAF.org
    org.iaaf.applications.IAAF
Incredipede
    air.com.northwaygames.Incredipede.humble
Isbjörn
    com.lge.livewallpaper.polarbear
Jelly
    com.jellyhq.starfish
Kalender
    com.google.android.calendar
Karateka
    com.freetoolsassociation.karateka.humble
Last.fm
    fm.last.android
Learn
    com.blackboard.android
LinkedIn
    com.linkedin.android
List My Apps
    de.onyxbits.listmyapps
McPixel
    air.gd.sos.mcpixel.humble
Mecenat
    se.mecenat.app
MEGA
    com.flyingottersoftware.mega
Messenger
    com.facebook.orca
Metal Slug 3
    com.dotemu.neogeo.mslug3.humble
Mickey? Free
    com.disney.wheresmymickeyfree_goo
Microsoft Remote Desktop
    com.microsoft.rdc.android
Mina Sidor
    se.forsakringskassan.android
MobiTime
    se.infospread.android.mobitime
My Panda Minion
    com.earlymorning.mypandaminion
Netflix
    com.netflix.mediaclient
NightSky HD
    com.nicalis.nightsky.humble
OnlinePizza
    se.onlinepizza
Organ Trail
    com.hatsproductions.OrganTrail.humble
Osmos HD
    com.hemispheregames.osmos.humble
Plants Vs Zombies
    com.popcap.pvz_humblebundle
Platsbanken
    com.arbetsformedlingen.activity
Plume
    com.levelup.touiteur
Pluralsight
    com.pluralsight
Podkicker
    ait.podka
POLARIS Office Viewer 5
    com.infraware.polarisviewer
Prisjakt
    se.prisjakt.pricespy
Prisjakt
    se.petersson.prisjakt
Punch Quest
    com.noodlecake.punchquest.humble
QuizCross
    se.maginteractive.quizcross
Quizkampen
    se.feomedia.quizkampen
Quizkampen PREMIUM
    se.feomedia.quizkampen.premium
QWOP
    com.noodlecake.QWOP.humble
Raiden Legacy
    com.dotemu.raidenlegacy.humble
Ravensword2
    com.crescentmoongames.ravensword2.humble
reseplanerare
    de.hafas.android.samtrafiken
Ridiculous Fishing
    com.vlambeer.RidiculousFishing.humble
RTLMobile
    se.realtimelight
RunKeeper
    com.fitnesskeeper.runkeeper.pro
Ruzzle
    se.maginteractive.rumble.free
rymdkapsel
    com.grapefrukt.games.rymdkapsel1.humble
S&S
    com.twotribes.sns.humble
Safety Care
    com.lge.safetycare
Samsung Galaxy Team
    se.samsung.challenge
SB Deluxe
    com.curvestudios.SBDeluxeHumble
SF Bio
    se.sfbio.mobile.android
Shazam
    com.shazam.android
SHL
    se.hockeyligan.elitserien1112
SJ Min resa
    se.sj.android
Skatteverket
    se.rsv.ef.mobil.android
Skype
    com.skype.raider
Smart Voice Recorder
    com.andrwq.recorder
SmartWorld
    com.lge.lgworld
SMHI Väder
    se.smhi.mobile.android
Smuggle Truck
    com.OwlchemyLabs.SmuggleTruck
Smugglers
    com.elevenbitstudios.HumbleBundle.FunkySmugglers
Snuggle Truck
    com.OwlchemyLabs.SnuggleTruck
Solar 2
    com.murudai.Solar2.humble
Songkick
    com.songkick
spelltower
    net.stfj.spelltower
Spirits
    com.spacesofplay.spirits.humble
Splice
    com.cipherprime.splice.humble
Sporcle
    com.sporcle
Spoticast
    com.nop.spoticast
Spotify
    com.spotify.mobile.android.ui
Stack Exchange
    com.stackexchange.marvin
Star Command
    com.starcommand.scgame.humble
Steam
    com.valvesoftware.android.steam.community
STHLM Traveling
    com.markupartist.sthlmtraveling
Strava
    com.strava.run
Super Hexagon
    com.distractionware.superhexagon.humble
Sveriges Radio Play
    se.sr.android
SVT Nyheter
    se.svt.svti.android.nyhetsapp
SVT Play
    air.se.svt.svti.android.svtplayer
Swedbank
    se.swedbank.mobil
Swish
    se.bankgirot.swish
Swordigo
    com.touchfoo.swordigo.humble
TED
    com.ted.android
TextTv
    se.texttv.app
The Last Panda
    se.re.lastpanda
The Room
    com.FireproofStudios.TheRoomHumble
Threes
    vo.threes.exclaim
Ticket to Ride
    com.daysofwonder.tt.android
Time Surfer
    com.kumobius.android.carpet.humble
tv.nu
    com.tvnu.app
TV4 Play
    se.tv4.tv4playtab
Tweedle
    com.handlerexploit.tweedle
Twitter
    com.twitter.android
Untappd
    com.untappdllc.app
Viaplay
    com.viaplay.android
Viasatsport
    se.viasat.video
Väder tema
    com.lge.sizechangable.weather.theme.optimus
Världstid widget
    com.lge.sizechangable.worldclock
Waking Mars
    com.tigerstylegames.wakingmars.humble
Wikipedia
    org.wikipedia
Wordfeud FREE
    com.hbwares.wordfeud.free
WordPress
    org.wordpress.android
World of Goo
    com.twodboy.worldofgoofull
Worms 2: Armageddon
    com.worms2armageddon.app.humble
Xbox 360 SmartGlass
    com.microsoft.smartglass
Zedge
    net.zedge.android
Zen Bound 2
    com.secretexit.zb2.humble
Översätt
    com.google.android.apps.translate
```

Comment: Can you post a list of the apps you've installed?

Comment: @KaranRajBaruah is there a simple way of exporting such a list?

Comment: Check this: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9824/how-can-i-export-a-list-of-currently-installed-applications-to-a-file

But I feel if you have way too many apps running in the background, they're the reason of your phone slowing down.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.onyxbits.listmyapps
Provides a list of your apps.

Comment: Okay, so I have like 170 installed apps. But only three of them run at this time (Stackexchange, Calls, Facebook)

Comment: My SO had this and the only thing that worked was a factory reset and gradually adding in the apps that she actually used.